# Lodash - return one of each type

Tags: lodash

I am just getting into Lodash. I'm sure I am missing something but, how do I remove duplicate entries in an array?

```
 [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]

 -> [0,1,2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do it through [`_.uniq`](https://lodash.com/docs#uniq)

```
> _.uniq([0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2])
  [0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: You're a star! knew it was simple! As a side note - how am i just finding Lodash now?